# How to let user enter payable amount in paytm payment using Node js

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, paytm

I am trying to make a payment portal using the paytm api.Through paytm's documentation i am able to do that but in that the params: 'transaction_amount' is being hardcoded.I was wondering how to get varying amounts form different users and pass the user's amount to the param 'transaction_amount'. I can get the amount through FORM from user with method="POST" but the paytm payment route is a "GET" route so even if my FORM goes to route action='/paytm' which is also my "GET" route for paytm payment it would'nt work.
Detailed help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter transaction_amount is not hard coded in any of the paytm APIs. It's just an example given in all the relevant API signatures. Kindly pass the amount as required through a variable for this parameter.